# Error while switching from parent to child window and vice versa in selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, window-handles

```
String Parentwindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ImageButton5']")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);

for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
System.out.println("Title of the page after - switchingTo: " + driver.getTitle());

driver.findElement(By.id("txtEnterCptCode")).sendKeys("99219");
//Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.id("btnSearch")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.id("chklstAllprocedure_0")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.id("btnOk")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);

/*ALL MODIFIERS 1*/

driver.switchTo().window(Parentwindow);
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
//Thread.sleep(4000);
driver.switchTo().frame("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_iframeID1");
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ImageButton17']")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
for(String winHandle1 : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle1);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
System.out.println("Title of the page after - switchingTo: " + driver.getTitle());
driver.findElement(By.id("txtEnterModifier")).sendKeys("RT");
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.id("btnSearch")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.id("chklstAllModifiers_0")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.id("btnOk")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

This is my code. Sometimes when I am trying to switch between parent and child windows, my code runs well without error and sometimes it shows this error message:

```
"Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information).
Command duration or timeout: 14 milliseconds".
```

Kindly help me out in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental flaw in the loop. Print the values of the Parentwindow and the values in the loop. The first value of the loop and the Parentwindow value will be same meaning you are not switching the child window. Please do let me know if you require more help.

Answer (score 1):

Your method doesnt guarantee to which window your driver will be switched .
I have an utility method to switch to the required window as shown below

```
public class Utility 
{
    public static WebDriver getHandleToWindow(String title){

        //parentWindowHandle = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getWindowHandle(); // save the current window handle.
        WebDriver popup = null;
        Set<String> windowIterator = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getWindowHandles();
        System.err.println("No of windows :  " + windowIterator.size());
        for (String s : windowIterator) {
          String windowHandle = s; 
          popup = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().switchTo().window(windowHandle);
          System.out.println("Window Title : " + popup.getTitle());
          System.out.println("Window Url : " + popup.getCurrentUrl());
          if (popup.getTitle().equals(title) ){
              System.out.println("Selected Window Title : " + popup.getTitle());
              return popup;
          }

        }
                System.out.println("Window Title :" + popup.getTitle());
                System.out.println();
            return popup;
        }
}
```

It will take you to desired window once title of the window is passed as parameter. In your case you can do.

`Webdriver childDriver = Utility.getHandleToWindow("titleOfChildWindow");`

and then again switch to parent window using the same method

```
Webdriver parentDriver = Utility.getHandleToWindow("titleOfParentWindow");
```

This method works effectively when dealing with multiple windows